# Combining multiple records into one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the following query:

```
DECLARE @Code varchar(6)

SELECT a.Code, a.Description, a.Time, b.id
FROM TableA a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.Code = @Code
```

The issue I'm having is it's returning multiple records because of the outer join, something like the following:

```
Code    Description     Time    B.id
5038    sample desc     4       108
5038    sample desc     4       632
5038    sample desc     4       633
5038    sample desc     4       197
5038    sample desc     4       503
```

What would be the best way to combine these into one record, with say a delimited list of b.id's?

Comment: I think this article might also help you [Combine Multiple Rows Into One Column with CSV output](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/03/sql-server-combine-multiple-rows-into.html).

Comment: @MikeCheel I did an outer join because not all TableA records will link to TableB.  Can you give an example of how I would use UNION ALL here?

Comment: I misread the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

For a delimited list you can go for XML Path clause. Here is the explanation: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/05/sql-server-group-by-rows-and-columns-using-xml-path-efficient-concating-trick/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method found [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/04/sql-server-create-a-comma-delimited-list-using-select-clause-from-table-column/)

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO

DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + Name
FROM Production.Product
SELECT @listStr
GO
```